# Como enviar mutiplas imagens com este codigo!

Tags: php, upload

Apenas esta enviando uma imagen!

**Meu Form**

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="./?action=addmult" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <div class="form-group">
           <label>Imagen (480x480)</label>
           <input type="file" name="image" multiple="">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <label>Pasta</label>
           <input type="text" name="folder" class="form-control" placeholder="Pasta">
          </div>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
```

Estou usando a [Class Upload](https://github.com/verot/class.upload.php/blob/master/README.md)!

**Meu código.**

```
if(isset($_FILES["image"])){
    $image=new Upload($_FILES["image"]);
    if($image->uploaded){
        $folder = 'teste';
        $new = mkdir($target_dir . $folder . "/");
        $image->Process("storage/images/".$folder);
        if($image->processed){
            $img = new ImageData();
            $p->title = $_POST["title"];
            $p->content = $_POST["content"];
            $img->src = $image->file_dst_name;
            $img->user_id=$_SESSION["user_id"];
            $imgx=$img->add();
        }
    }
}
Core::redir("./?view=galery");
```

**Tentativa**

```
        if(isset($_FILES["image"])){

    $handle=new Upload($_FILES["image"]);
    $files = array();
    foreach ($_FILES['image'] as $k => $l) {
    foreach ($l as $i => $v) {
    if (!array_key_exists($i, $files))
    $files[$i] = array();
    $files[$i][$k] = $v;
    }
    }
    foreach ($files as $file) {
    $handle = new Upload($file);
    if($handle->uploaded){

    $folder = $_POST["folder"];
    $new = mkdir($target_dir . $folder . "/");
    $handle->Process("storage/images/".$folder);

    if($handle->processed){

        $img = new ImageData();
        $p->title = $_POST["title"];
        $p->content = $_POST["content"];
        $img->src = $image->file_dst_name;
        $img->user_id=$_SESSION["user_id"];
        $imgx=$img->add();
        echo 'OK';
        } else {
        echo 'Error: ' . $handle->error;
        }
        } else {
        echo 'Error: ' . $handle->error;
        }
        unset($handle);
      }

    Core::redir("./?view=galery");
```

Comment: As classes Upload e ImageData não são nativas, logo **é impossível** responder a sua pergunta, pois nem sabemos se isso é um framework ou um código proprio e portanto desconhecemos o básico para poder fornecer qualquer ajuda.

Comment: você, não deve ter entendido a informação sobre ! Apenas esta enviando uma imagen! onde esta o wally ?

Comment: Sem conhecer o código não temos como afirmar como dizer com precisão qual o uso correto (ou mais adequado) para o upload, afinal de contas se é um código pessoal seu (me refiro as classes) só você saberia afirmar, se for um Framework popular então só se você informar qual é e qual a sua versão. PS: só pra avisar não fui eu quem deu o downvote.

Comment: tudo funciona imagedata e Upload o que acontece que nao esta enviando multiplas imagens e apenas uma imagen eh enviada !
criação de pasta , envio de imagen tudo ok!
como se trata de apenas uma classe como no link acima da mesma acredito , que não preciso mostrar que é um framework ou qualquer outra coisa ! pois a pergunta que eu fiz relacionada apenas ao upload inclusive encontrei este https://github.com/verot/class.upload.php/issues/1

Comment: Está chegando um array em `$_FILES["image"]`?

Comment: nao! nao chega nada.

Answer (score 1):

Agradeço a todos pela ajuda !

com muito custo descobri o problema e estou passando a solução para todos
 Obrigado !

Codigo Reformulado!

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="./?action=addmult" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label>Selecione as imagens</label>
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Pasta</label>
                <input type="text" name="folder" class="form-control" placeholder="Pasta">
            </div>
    <div class="file-loading">
        <input id="file-0c" class="file" type="file" name="image[]" multiple data-min-file-count="0">
    </div>
```

Enviar

A solução encontrada foi de apenas um [] no **name="image" para name ="image[]"**